# When should I prefer write-combined CUDA-allocated mapped host memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, cuda, gpgpu

the `cudaHostAlloc()` API call has, among others, the flags:

> - cudaHostAllocMapped: Maps the allocation into the CUDA address space. The device pointer to the memory may be obtained by calling cudaHostGetDevicePointer().
> - cudaHostAllocWriteCombined: Allocates the memory as write-combined (WC). WC memory can be transferred across the PCI Express bus more quickly **on some system configurations,** but cannot be read efficiently by most CPUs. WC memory is a good option for buffers that will be written by the CPU and read by the device via mapped pinned memory or host->device transfers.

I could quite understand when exactly I would prefer the "write-combined" option. I mean, it didn't say the transfer may be faster just in one direction, so why do they only recommend it for one direction? Also, which kind of systems benefit from this "write-combining"?

I read [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/0_Simple/simpleZeroCopy/doc/CUDA2.2PinnedMemoryAPIs.pdf) white paper, Section 4.7, and still could not get it. Ok, so reading by the CPU is inefficient; but what if other benefits offset this inefficiency? Or - if they cannot, why can't they?

An elucidation would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, I'll transfer the comment into an answer. I am not up to speed on where WC memory is still used. I recall it first was introduced with the Pentium Pro around 1995, and its main use was to allow faster CPU writes to the framebuffers of video cards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write-combined memory allows the CPU to combine multiple narrow writes into fewer wider writes, thus increasing the efficiency of memory writes. If memory serves, WC memory was first introduced with the Intel PentiumPro around 1995 to speed up CPU writes into the frame buffer of video cards. I am not up to speed on which modern system platforms use or support this.

The efficiency of reads performed by the CPU is going to be the same for both `cudaHostAllocMapped` and `cudaHostAllocWriteCombined`. But because the latter allows more efficient *writes* by the CPU, it is recommended for "buffers that will be written by the CPU and read by the device", as stated by quoted documentation.